# Can anyone explain the output of variable byte in this case, it is occuring in negative

Tags: java, variables, byte, type-mismatch

**I know it is out of range for byte**

```
public class TypeMismatchVariable {

    byte b = (byte) 129;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TypeMismatchVariable t1 = new TypeMismatchVariable();
        System.out.println(t1.b);
    }

}
```

**In this case I'm having -127 as my output**
**But I don't have any reason for it**

Comment: "I know it is out of range for byte", "But I don't have any reason for it" - That is exactly the reason why the values appears as -127. It is too big for byte so it overflows.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Byte range is from minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

For byte type, you only have 8 bits to store the value. You can have only 256 distinct values (2^8 = 256). Java represents negative values with '1' as the highest bit:

```
-128 (dec) => 10000000 (bit)
-127 (dec) => 10000001 (bit)
... 
-1   (dec) => 11111111 (bit)
0    (dec) => 00000000 (bit)
+1   (dec) => 00000001 (bit)
+127 (dec) => 01111111 (bin)
```

When you try to set a value that needs more than one byte to store then setting the lowest byte to a byte value happens:

```
+129 (dec) => 00000000 00000000 00000000 10000001  (int representation)
```

but 10000001 (bit) is -127 (dec) in byte representation of java type (as described above)
To have a better understanding of the overflow problem in Java, see the article: https://medium.com/@jeanvillete/java-numeric-overflow-underflow-d6b206f96d88